# jQuery tokeninput search across multiple fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I installed the JQuery token-input plugin.  https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput
Autocomplete is working, but I have a situation where I am search across multiple model attributes.  For example, I have a drug Model and the model attributes include name and active ingredient

I am using the meta_where gem to search across multiple fields, and it is working correctly; checking the json output shows that my Drug.where() method is returning the correct result rows.  However, on the front-end side, jQuery is populating the autocomplete box with only the name of the drug.  How do I get jQuery to display multiple model attributes in the autocomplete box?  Ideally, I would like to display something like "model.name (model.active_ingredient)" in the autocomplete dropdown.  Right now, jQuery tokeninput is fetching the correct rows, but displaying only the name.  How do I get the other attributes of the model to show up?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could combine the name  and active_ingredient for the json,
because, all you can use is the name: "Aspirin (Mentol)"

when you return it from the controller, and seperate it, like you need it.

(in your Drug model)

```
def fullname
  "#{name} (#{active_ingrdient})"
end
```

all you need is to set the name: parameter in the json fill with your fullname attribute

```
format.json do
  render :json => @drugs.map { |drug| drug.as_json(:only => :id, :methods => :name) }
end
```

to set it manually:

```
format.json do
  render :json => @drugs.map { |drug|  {:id => drug.id, :name => drug.fullname} }
end
```

hope that helps you further

Comment: Thanks; this is exactly what I was looking for.  For those interested, I also had to map my own names for the autocomplete box prepopulation.

**'data-pre' => (@meds.map { |med| {:id => med.id, :name => med.med_display_text}}.to_json**

Comment: Hey @radosch, I just realized that after putting in this code, the autocomplete no longer highlights the part of the name that matches the user's typed input.  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I have to investigate it first, keep you updated (can take a while, cause weekend ;)